# Simulation stops after certain UI elements are used

Tags: processing

Im working on a project in processing, and I'm having some difficulty with this super annoying bug. All the code is pasted below, 4 class files.

Whenever the "Simulation speed" slider is moved up and then moved back down, the simulation will stop giving no errors. Same thing with the "Auto" button. I have no idea why this is occurring and I've gone through my code following the variables and I don't see anything wrong.

Help!

**noisedemo** file

```
int tableHeight = 20;
int tableWidth = 20;
float prismWidth = 10;
float tableTopx = 260;
float tableTopy = 200;
int k = 0;

int simulationSpeed;
int frameCounter;

Prism[][] prisms = new Prism[tableWidth][tableHeight];

//Declare the sliders

Slider simulationSpeedSlider = new Slider(10, 20, 100, 30, "Simulation Speed");
Slider noiseOctaveSlider = new Slider(10, 50, 100, 4, "Noise Ocatave");
Slider noiseScaleSlider = new Slider(10, 80, 100, 10, 10, "Noise Scale", true);

//Declare the buttons

Button autoScrollButton = new Button(400, 100, "Auto");

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
  smooth();
  pixelDensity(2);
  frameRate(30);
  noiseDetail((int)noiseOctaveSlider.sliderValue, noiseScaleSlider.sliderValue);  
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
      prisms[i][j] = new Prism(noise(i, j)*30+10, prismWidth);
      prisms[i][j].setHeight(noise(i, j)*30+10);
    }
  }
}

float[] convertCoordinate(int xcoord, int ycoord, float xtop, float ytop, float pwidth){
  float[] coord = new float[2];
  
  coord[0] = (xtop + xcoord*cos(radians(40))*prismWidth - ycoord * cos(radians(40))*prismWidth)*0.95;
  coord[1] = (ytop + ycoord*sin(radians(40))*prismWidth + xcoord * sin(radians(40))*prismWidth)*0.95;
  
  return coord;
}

void updateHeight(){
  for(int i = 0; i < tableWidth; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < tableHeight; j++){
      prisms[i][j].drawPrism(convertCoordinate(i, j, tableTopx, tableTopy, prismWidth)[0], convertCoordinate(i, j, tableTopx, tableTopy, prismWidth)[1]);
    }
  }
}

void setHeight(){
  for(int i = 0; i < tableWidth; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < tableHeight; j++){
      prisms[i][j].setHeight(noise(i+k, j+k)*30+10);
    }
  }
}

void mouseClicked(){
  if(autoScrollButton.isInRange()){
    autoScrollButton.buttonActive = !autoScrollButton.buttonActive;
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0, 150, 0);
  noiseDetail((int)noiseScaleSlider.sliderValue, noiseScaleSlider.sliderValue);
  
  simulationSpeedSlider.drawSlider();
  simulationSpeed = (int)simulationSpeedSlider.sliderValue;
  noiseOctaveSlider.drawSlider();
  noiseScaleSlider.drawSlider();
  
  autoScrollButton.drawButton();
  
  if(frameCounter == simulationSpeed && autoScrollButton.buttonActive){
    k++;
    frameCounter = 0;
    setHeight();
  }
  
  updateHeight();
  
  frameCounter++;
}
```

**button** file

```
class Button{
  
  boolean buttonActive = true;
  float buttonX;
  float buttonY;
  float buttonWidth = 30;
  float buttonHeight = 15;
  String buttonLabel;
  
  Button(float x, float y, String label){
    buttonX = x;
    buttonY = y;
    buttonLabel = label;
  }
  
  
  void drawButton(){
    
    
    if(!buttonActive){
      fill(100);
      rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, 5);
  
      fill(255);
      text(buttonLabel, buttonX + 4, buttonY + 10);
    }else{
      fill(200);
      rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, 5);
  
      fill(0);
      text(buttonLabel, buttonX + 4, buttonY + 10);
    }
    
    }
  
  boolean isInRange(){
    
    if(mouseX > buttonX && mouseX < buttonX + buttonWidth && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY + buttonHeight){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

**prism** file

```
class Prism{
  
  float pheight;
  float pwidth;
  
  Prism(float tempheight, float tempwidth){
    pheight = tempheight;
    pwidth = tempwidth;
  }
  
  Prism(){
    pheight = 10;
    pwidth = 5;
  }
  
  void drawPrism(float x, float y){
    noStroke();
    fill(175);
    quad(x, y, x - cos(radians(40))*pwidth, y - sin(radians(40))*pwidth, x - cos(radians(40))*pwidth, y - sin(radians(40))*pwidth - pheight, x, y - pheight);
    fill(100);
    quad(x, y, x + cos(radians(40))*pwidth, y - sin(radians(40))*pwidth, x + cos(radians(40))*pwidth, y - sin(radians(40))*pwidth - pheight, x, y - pheight);
    fill(225);
    quad(x, y - pheight, x - cos(radians(40))*pwidth, y - sin(radians(40))*pwidth - pheight, x, y - 2*sin(radians(40))*pwidth - pheight, x + cos(radians(40))*pwidth, y - sin(radians(40))*pwidth - pheight);
  }
  
  void setHeight(float tempheight){
    pheight = tempheight;
  }
  
}
```

**slider** file

```
class Slider{
  
  float sliderLength;
  float sliderX;
  float sliderY;
  float sliderWidth;
  float handleWidth;
  float sliderValue;
  float sliderPos;
  int sliderTotal;
  
  boolean handleActive;
  boolean isPrecise;
  String sliderLabel;
  
  //provide x and y position, length and the max value, the least amount of info
  Slider(float x, float y, float slength, int total){
    sliderX = x;
    sliderY = y;
    sliderLength = slength;
    sliderWidth = 10;
    handleWidth = sliderWidth*1.5;
    sliderTotal = total;
    sliderPos = sliderX + sliderWidth/2;
    sliderLabel = "";
  }
  
  //provide x and y position, length and the max value AND a label
  Slider(float x, float y, float slength, int total, String label){
    sliderX = x;
    sliderY = y;
    sliderLength = slength;
    sliderWidth = 10;
    handleWidth = sliderWidth*1.5;
    sliderTotal = total;
    sliderPos = sliderX + sliderWidth/2;
    sliderLabel = label;
  }
  
  //provide default values AND a label AND a width AND whether its precise
  Slider(float x, float y, float slength, float swidth, int total, String label, boolean p){
    sliderX = x;
    sliderY = y;
    sliderLength = slength;
    sliderWidth = swidth;
    handleWidth = sliderWidth*1.5;
    sliderTotal = total;
    sliderPos = sliderX + sliderWidth/2;
    sliderLabel = label;
    isPrecise = p;
  }
  
  void drawSlider(){
    fill(255);
    textSize(10);
    text(sliderLabel, sliderX, sliderY - 5);
    text(sliderValue, sliderX + sliderLength + 7, sliderY + sliderWidth/1.1);
    
    fill(100);
    rect(sliderX-1, sliderY, sliderLength+1, sliderWidth, 5);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(sliderPos, sliderY + (sliderWidth/2), handleWidth, handleWidth);
    
    if(!isPrecise){
      sliderValue = (int)((sliderPos - sliderX)/(sliderLength/sliderTotal));
    }else if(isPrecise){
      sliderValue = (sliderPos - sliderX)/(sliderLength/sliderTotal);
    }
    
    if(mouseX >= sliderX && mouseX <= sliderX+sliderLength + sliderX && mouseY >= sliderY - (handleWidth/2) && mouseY <= sliderY + (handleWidth/2) && mousePressed){
      handleActive = true;
    }
    if(!mousePressed){
      handleActive = false;
    }
    if(handleActive && sliderPos <= sliderX + sliderLength && sliderPos >= sliderX){
      sliderPos = mouseX;
    }
    if(sliderPos > sliderX + sliderLength){
      sliderPos = sliderX + sliderLength;
    }
    if(sliderPos < sliderX){
      sliderPos = sliderX + 1;
    }
  }
  
}
```

Thank you! Sorry if the code is a little messy :)

Answer (score 1):

In your main file, this block relies on the values of those two controls:

```
if(frameCounter == simulationSpeed && autoScrollButton.buttonActive){
  k++;
  frameCounter = 0;
  setHeight();
}
```

When that gets skipped (because you changed `simulationSpeed` or `buttonActive`), your `frameCounter` gets out of sync with `simulationSpeed` so the block continues to get skipped.